# Sort the array so that zero values are at the bottom of each group and the remaining values are sorted alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

It is necessary to sort the array so that values with the same currentUser are on top and these values are sorted by name, if there is no name, then it is necessary to sort them down each group.

```
const currentUser = 256;
const settings = [
  {
    name: null,
    userId: 256,
  },
  {
    name: 'Bear',
    userId: 256,
  },
  {
    name: 'Anatomy',
    userId: 256,
  },
  {
    name: null,
    userId: 12,
  },
  {
    name: null,
    userId: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'Anatomy',
    userId: 43,
  },
];

settings.sort((a, b) => {
  const aName = a.name || null;
  const bName = b.name || null;

  return (
    (aName === null) - (bName === null) ||
    Number(b.userId === currentUser) - Number(a.userId === currentUser) ||
    aName - bName
  );
});

console.log(settings);
```

The result should be an array:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Anatomy',
    userId: 256,
  },
  {
    name: 'Bear',
    userId: 256,
  },
  {
    name: null,
    userId: 256,
  },
  {
    name: 'Anatomy',
    userId: 43,
  },
  {
    name: null,
    userId: 12,
  },
  {
    name: null,
    userId: 23,
  },
]
```

I would appreciate any help, best regards, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the ordering followed in the code:

- Give highest preference to `userId`'s matching `currentUser` and if two `userId`'s match `currentUser`, then sort them alphabetically by their `name` and for `null` names put them at the last (*in that group*).
- Sort other items by their `userId` in descending order.
- For items that have same `userId`, again sort them alphabetically by their `name` and for `null` names put them at the last (*in that group*).

```js
const currentUser = 43;
const settings = [
  { name: null, userId: 256 },
  { name: null, userId: 43 },
  { name: "Abby", userId: 43 },
  { name: "Bear", userId: 256 },
  { name: "John", userId: 256 },
  { name: "Simon", userId: 43 },
  { name: null, userId: 12 },
  { name: null, userId: 23 },
  { name: "Anatomy", userId: 43 },
];

function sortByName(a, b) {
  if (Object.is(a, null) && Object.is(b, null)) {
    return 0;
  } else if (Object.is(a, null)) {
    return 1;
  } else if (Object.is(b, null)) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  }
}

settings.sort((a, b) => {
  // Objects that have same `userId` as `currentUser`
  if (a.userId === currentUser && b.userId === currentUser) {
    return sortByName(a.name, b.name);
  } else if (a.userId === currentUser) {
    return -1;
  } else if (b.userId === currentUser) {
    return 1;
  }

  // Other objects
  if (a.userId > b.userId) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.userId < b.userId) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return sortByName(a.name, b.name);
  }
});

console.log(settings);
```

Comment: You need to sort like this:
Sort those values with UserId that are equal to currentUsser up, the rest down, and sort all these values in sorted groups by name, where all null values are sorted down

He result should be:

```
{ name: "Bear", userId: 256 },
{ name: "John", userId: 256 },
{ name: null, userId: 256 },

{ name: "Abby", userId: 43 },
{ name: "Anatomy", userId: 43 },
{ name: "Simon", userId: 43 },
{ name: null, userId: 43 },
{ name: null, userId: 12 },
{ name: null, userId: 23 },
```

Comment: @Vladislav That's exactly what my solution does, and I'm assuming that you want to sort the groups by their `userId`, right?

Comment: @Vladislav I've updated `currentUser` to `43` in my example, you can change it to `256` and it would work.

Comment: thanks, everything works as it should!